# Connected components in a graph with 100 million nodes

Tags: python, graph

I am trying to get the list of connected components in a graph with 100 million nodes. For smaller graphs, I usually use the [connected_components](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components) function of the Networkx module in Python which does exactly that. However, loading a graph with 100 million nodes (and their edges) into memory with this module would require ca. 110GB of memory, which I don't have. An alternative would be to use a graph database which has a connected components function but I haven't found any in Python. It would seem that Dex (API: Java, .NET, C++) has this functionality but I'm not 100% sure. Ideally I'm looking for a solution in Python. Many thanks.

Comment: How dense is your graph? What's the average vertex degree?

Comment: Is the graph directed? If it is - are you looking for *Strongly* connected components or connected components? Also - I assume you are looking for *Maximal* [strongly?] connected components, and not all of them (since their number is exponential) - is it true?

Comment: @aix: the graph has on average 1.5 vertex/node.

Comment: @amit: the graph is undirected. I am looking for a way to get the list of connected components, exactly as networkx.connected_components does but on a larger scale.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SciPy has a [connected components algorithm](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components.html). It expects as input the adjacency matrix of your graph in one of its [sparse matrix formats](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) and handles both the directed and undirected cases.

Building a sparse adjacency matrix from a sequence of `(i, j)` pairs `adj_list` where `i` and `j` are (zero-based) indices of nodes can be done with

```
i_indices, j_indices = zip(*adj_list)
adj_matrix = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((np.ones(number_of_nodes),
                                     (i_indices, j_indices)))
```

You'll have to do some extra work for the undirected case.

This approach should be efficient if your graph is sparse enough.

Comment: My graph is pretty sparse but this solution works only for a (relatively) small graph, because the time penalty of scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components is not linear. In my test it took 0.4 second to process 10,000 nodes; 30 seconds for 100,000 nodes and 51 minutes for 1 million (then I stopped testing). Thanks for suggesting this anyway, it is an interesting approach.

Comment: @user1453508: that's odd. I checked the code and at first glance it seems to me that it should be linear when |E| = O(|V|). I must admit that my graphs tend to be a bit smaller. Maybe you should start looking at MapReduce solutions to your problem.

Comment: Just in case I have misunderstood something, here is my code: `i_indices = [];
j_indices = [];
file = open ('adjacency_file.txt', 'r');
for line in iter(file):
    i_index, j_index = line.strip('\n').split('\t');
    i_indices.append(i_index);
    j_indices.append(j_index);
file.close();
adjacency_matrix = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((np.ones(len(i_indices)),(i_indices, j_indices)), shape=(10000,10000));
connected_components = scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components(adjacency_matrix, directed=False)`

Comment: @user1453508: looks like you're assigning strings to `i_index` and `j_index`, and then storing those in the index lists. I'm not sure how the `coo_matrix` constructor will handle that, but it sure isn't the intended input.

Comment: Originally my nodes are 10-digit numbers and I have converted them into indices from 0 to 10,000, which are stored into adjacency_file.txt (e.g. if node 5 is linked to node 22, the file will contain the line 5[tab]22[\n]). Is that the correct way to do it?

Comment: @user1453508: the point is that after the `.split('\t')`, you don't call `int` on its results, so they're still strings. I'd try converting them to `int` to see if that helps.

Comment: Ah yes, I got used in the past to implicit type conversion when I learnt Perl... bad habit :( However, I have now turned the indices into integers but connected_components takes the same time to run. I'll try to see if I can find something with MapReduce. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have finally managed to find the connected components using a union-find algorithm (such as the one described [here](http://chasebradford.wordpress.com/2010/10/23/mapreduce-implementation-for-union-find/), which I have written in Python without the MapReduce, but had I needed Hadoop I could have used [Mr Job](http://packages.python.org/mrjob/writing-and-running.html)).

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this approach! Using sparse matrices and scipy is much more efficient than using NetworkX. The sparse-matrix memory representation takes much less RAM, solving our scalability issues.

Answer (score 3):

https://graph-tool.skewed.de/performance

this tool as you can see from performance is very fast. It's written in C++ but the interface is in Python.

If this tool isn't good enough for you. (Which I think it will) then you can try Apache Giraph (http://giraph.apache.org/).